# Should i commit at the end of the procedure which is called by an oracle scheduler job

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, job-scheduling

I am running an oracle `JOB` which will run a `PROCEDURE` to `CREATE` `TRUNCATE` `INSERT` `DROP` some relevant tables.

**Is this the best way to do a functionality like this ?
Should I Commit at the end of the procedure or not ?**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure PR_NAME 
IS 
BEGIN

   CREATE TABLE TABLE_1_BAC AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1_VIA_DBLINK;

   TRUNCATE TABLE  TABLE_1;

   INSERT INTO TABLE_1   SELECT * FROM TABLE_1_BAC;

   DROP TABLE TABLE_1_BAC;

--COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE ...` is a DDL command which makes an implicit COMMIT, so in your case it is not required.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is this the best way to handle this situation or should i write dynamic sql to handle this

Comment: You must use dynamic SQL (i.e. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '...'` anyway.

Comment: You should always avoid `SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM`. If you just want to re-raise an existing exception without adding any value, then just use `raise` - although normally that should follow some other processing such as logging a message. If you don't even want that, then why wreck a perfectly good error stack with a nonsensical, mangled message?

Answer (score 0):

To create `TABLE_1` only once for present data :

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1_VIA_DBLINK;
```

and creating an insert trigger for `TABLE1_VIA_DBLINK`, populating `TABLE_1` through this trigger for new datas, and to get rid of this `job` and `procedure` seems more feasible.

As you stay in this job, perhaps you'll wait for huge data to be inserted.

By the way, if you insist on using this job, you don't need to issue `commit`, since and there's already an implicit `commit` exists inside `job` mechanism.

Comment: there are 15 tables which i will be handling in the same procedure and an not sure if writing triggers on all those tables is a best practice , because the `TABLE1_VIA_DBLINK` is access over a DBKLINK from another part of the country.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of job do you use? `JOB` or `SCHEDULER JOB`?

I don't see any reason to DROP/CREATE the table. I don't see any reason why you use the intermediate table at all.

Simply make

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure PR_NAME 
IS 
BEGIN

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_1';
   INSERT INTO TABLE_1 SELECT * FROM TABLE1_VIA_DBLINK;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

You don't need any exception handler. In case of `JOB` you will not see the exception anyway. In case of `SCHEDULER JOB` you can see exception in views

```
*_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG

*_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
```

If you make just this kind of operation you should consider [MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302) which basically make the same: `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: i am running a SCHEDULER JOB

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't need to commit.

Those commands are DDL (Data Definition Language) in SQL. So Oracle Database will issue a commit together with the command.

DML (Data Manipulating Language) - like SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE requires a commit.

In a scenario, where you will update, delete and insert records. Then you ran a create table command. The records inserted, updated and deleted will be committed (save) to the database.